# How do I output a value without placing it into the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, function, sumifs

I have a pretty simple Sub that contains the following code -

```
Sub UnitNetCheck()
    Dim UnitValue As Integer
    Dim NetArea As Long

    If Not [COUNTA(F2:F250)=0] Then
        For UnitValue = 2 To 250
            Cells(UnitValue, 26) = Cells(UnitValue, 4) * Cells(UnitValue, 6)
            If Cells(UnitValue, 26) = 0 Then
                Cells(UnitValue, 26).Value = ""
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Else
        NetArea = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Z2:Z" & NetArea).Value = 
            Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G250").Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

This sub `UnitNetCheck`, right now all it does is multiply some cells with some other cells and places the values in `Z2:Z250`.

Instead of it outputting the values into the specific range noted, I would like to instead use the output in other code without it populating on the worksheet.

What I would like to do is later use the sub as part of a worksheet SUMIF function as `Sumif("defined range")("defined criteria")(UnitNetCheck Sub)`.

Comment: Do you mean to save the values for later use in code, without saving them to the worksheet? If so, can you accept saving the values in an array that is defined in a public module? Also, there are two IF statements, which one?

Comment: @icodeplenty seems like arrays is most likely the case here, I just need to get them to work now :P Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the data for later use in code, you need to create a module level variable (like a global in other languages) that is an array type.

First step is to create the array, so from the VBA Editor menu, select Insert->Module, then past the following:

```vb
'Declare the array inside a module file
Dim CellData(250)
```

Next step is to save the data from your existing code, like this:

```vb
For UnitValue = 2 To 250
Cells(UnitValue, 26) = Cells(UnitValue, 4) * Cells(UnitValue, 6)
    If Cells(UnitValue, 26) = 0 Then
    Cells(UnitValue, 26).Value = ""
    Else
        'Save in array for later use
        CellData(UnitValue) = Cells(UnitValue, 26).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Module-level variable is one option. A `Function` instead of a Sub is another, and probably better practice.